# Basics of automated tests?

Tags: php, theory, test-suite

Till now I've been testing my web (usually written in PHP) as well as desktop applications (normally Java or C#) manually. Now I read somewhere on the net about automated tests. I tried searching to know about it in details but almost all searches end up at things like PHPUnit. Could someone please put some light on the theory behind automated tests? How a software can be tested automatically? Any limitations etc? Or may be you can tell me a place where I can read about this.

Regards

Comment: If you ended up at PHPUnit, you ended up fine, because that's what you would want to use for automated testing. That and Selenium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing the correctness of code you can use [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). This was first explained to me from [Dive Into Python: Unit Testing](http://diveintopython.net/unit_testing/index.html) and will do much more justice to the topic then I could here. Now that you know about the term unit testing, you shouldn't be far from other existing explanations that will make sense to you, be it that one doesn't.

You may find [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) of interest too.

Your code is not magically tested for you, as you may had the idea of. The code to test your application will be written by you. What packages like PHPUnit offer you is a framework in which you can implement your tests. These packages will provide many conveniences for defining your tests, running them together as a suite, and generating a report. These are the only automated aspects.

Answer (score 1):

These Test Tools are used in the following manner as, If suppose we have to test a webform we will pas the input data into the fields they have provided us with the tool, and the number of users needs to filling the form (their user-name), In this way when this is executed then the form gets filled with provided data with individual usernames, This execution may provide u test data as performance, time of execution and load etc...

[WebLoad Testing Tutorial](http://techpubs.borland.com/silk_gauntlet/SilkPerformer/2007/WebLoadTestingTutorial.pdf)

see the above link for load testing...

See these links as well
[Functional testing](http://www.testingbrain.com/TOOLS/Web_test_tools/Functional_Test_Tools.html)

[Security Testing](http://www.testingbrain.com/TOOLS/Web_test_tools/Security_Test_Tools.html)

[Link and HTML tool Testing](http://www.testingbrain.com/TOOLS/Web_test_tools/Link_Html_Test_Tools.html)

[Performance Testing](http://www.testingbrain.com/TOOLS/Web_test_tools/Link_Html_Test_Tools.html)

Comment: Why do people do that? If you're going to vote someone down at least have basic courtesy to leave a note explaining why! Anyway, I don't see a problem with Perth's answers, so back to 0 he goes...

Comment: Thanks Martin... Even I am fed Up of These people... Thanks Again

Comment: Thanks Parth, your answer helped me understand what I was seeking to.

Comment: I may feel like a noob but.. ummm I don't know what "n e time" means. :(

Comment: Aah... Ok, you added something more to my knowledge. But if I say thanks again, it will be become infinite recursion lol. :)